Solving the coupon problem and I'm unsure
I am studying probability with the book "A first course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross and the following problem is a bit irritating me:

There are $N$ distinct types of coupons, and each time one is obtained it will, independently of past choices, be of type $i$ with probability $P(i),i = 1,...,N$. Let $T$ denote the number one need select to obtain at least one of each type. Compute $P(T = n)$.

To compute $P(T = n)$, I derived the following:

$P(T = N)$ = P(all cards at once) = $P_1P_2P_3P_4...P_N * N!$

$P(T = N+1) =$ P(last card is the one that I haven't picked up) = $P_1^2 P_2 P_3 P_4 ⋯ P_N * N * N! + P_1 P_2^2 P_3 P_4 ⋯ P_N * N * N! + ⋯$

$P(T = n) = P_1P_2P_3P_4⋯ P_N(P_1^{n-N} + P_2^{n-N} + ⋯ +P_N^{n-N})(N+1)(N+1)!$


There is no single solution which tells me that way. Could anyone tell me if I am in the right way?

Your expression for $N+1$ is not correct.  The first term attempts to calculate the chance that you get $2$ of coupon number $1$ and one of each other out of $N+1$ coupons.  With the $N \cdot N!$ you are trying to compute the number of orders you can draw those coupons.  It looks like you are saying there are $N$ positions (why not $N+1$?) for one of those, then $N!$ ways to put the rest in order.  You are double counting because you could count either of the coupon $1$s as the first and the other as the second.  You should say there are ${N+1 \choose 2}$ ways to choose where the two coupon $1$s go, then $(N-1)!$ ways to order the rest.  Then you can note that ${N+1 \choose 2}(N-1)!=\frac 12(N+1)!$.  Your last equation is badly wrong as it assumes that all the extra coupons need to be the same type, but they could be many different types.  I don't think there is a nice formula for this.

oh, I didn't figure out that one. thank you!
